# Can't find opencv sources

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, opencv, compilation

I try to learn openCV to build an application using openGL + Qt, and maybe CUDA. These librairies are not supported in the prebuild version on sourceforge. So I thought I could build them.
 But the tuto on opencv.org say that I have to use Cmake on the Source folder, but I can't find it... And it's not on the git repo. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They provide the libraries on [svn](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv). Or you can also download the sources from the linux version. CMake is a multiplatform tool, after all